# How to obtain queue capacity and load in zero-mq

Tags: python, zeromq, pyzmq

I have a publisher-subscriber architecture in ZeroMQ. I use Python.

I need to be able to tell when some queue is about to be too full, and preferably be able to do something about it.

I must be able to know if messages are lost.

I am, however, unable to find the relevant documentation on this subject.

Would love some help

Thanks!

Comment: I ended up using a double buffer wrapper arround my ZMQ handling class. It uses a polling thread to get everything in zmq into an internal buffer over which I have control.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet of what I did

```
def _flush_zmq_into_buffer(self):
    # poll zmq for new messages. if any are found, put all possible items from zmq to self.buffer
    # if many readers, need to use a read-write lock with writer priority
    # http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577803-reader-writer-lock-with-priority-for-writers/
    while True:
        self._iteration += 1
        self._flush_zmq_once()
        sleep(0.005)

def _take_work_from_buffer(self):
    while True:
        try:
            if self._buffer.qsize() > 0:
                work_message = self._buffer.get(block=True)
                # can't have any heavy operation here! this has to be as lean as possible!
            else:
                sleep(0.01)
                continue
        except queue.Empty as ex:
            sleep(0.01)
            continue

        self._work_once(work_message)

def _flush_zmq_once(self):
    self.__tick()

    flushed_messages = 0
    for i in range(self.max_flush_rate):
        try:
            message = self._parse_single_zmq_message()
            self._buffer.put(message, block=True)  # must block. can't lose messages.
        except zmq.Again:  # zmq empty
            flushed_messages = i
            break

    self._log_load(flushed_messages)

    self.__tock()
    self.__print_flushed(flushed_messages)
```

This allows me to flush the zmq buffer into my own buffer much faster than I am parsing messages, thus not losing any message, and paying with latency.

This also allows me to know how many messages are flushed from zmq every flushing cycle, thus having an idea about the load.

The reason this is using polling over events, is that for a high rate of incoming messages, the event system would be more costly than the polling system. The last sentence is untested, but I believe it to be true.